# How can I get row index if every cell is a child component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html-table

I am currently trying to create a table where row index needs to be displayed for every row. 
I thought this was a simple task, but I soon realized that it is out of my knowledge.

---

The table iterates (maps) through a fetched JSON file (this.state)
and creates a component by **React.createElement** with the props, "player", from **this.state.body.map()**

**Below is the table component**

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <table className="ranked_table">
                    <tbody>
                    {this.state.body.map(player => React.createElement(Cell, player))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <button id="vote_btn"><a>RANK</a></button>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

**And below is the row component**

```
render() {
        return (
            <tr className="row">
                <th>{**DESIRED RANK COLUMN**}</th>
                <th>
                    <div className="image_border">
                        <img src={this.props.image} className="profile_pic" alt="" >
                        </img>
                        <div className="medal"></div>
                    </div></th>
                <th><div className="name">{this.props.name}</div></th>
                <th>
                    <a className="upVote">
                        <img src="/asset/vote_btn.svg"></img>
                    </a>
                </th>
                <th className="count">{this.props.count}</th>
            </tr>
        );
    }
```

**How can I create a row index column?** I tried to modify the state object that is passed as props to the row component, but I got stuck there too.

Comment: `map((player, i) =>` then pass `i` as prop to the `Cell` (row?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` function passes the current index to its callback function. You can pass that index to row component

```
this.state.body.map((player, index) => React.createElement(Cell, {player, rowNum: index}))
```

as `index` starts from zero, you probably want to add one to each index value when passing it as prop

```
React.createElement(Cell, {player, rowNum: index + 1 })
```

Comment:  I guess the solution was in fact simple! Thank you so much. ** I noticed that it should be index++ instead of index+1**